# how to use DateAdd in while

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I create a function to get date of the next four weeks.For do this I use belowe code . but i does'nt complie and get error .

```
    create function GetNextDays()
returns @somedays table
(

dayDate date
)
as
begin
declare @today date=getdate()
declare @index int=0
while @index<3
    begin
    insert @somedays(dayDate) values(@today)
    set @index=@index+1;
     DATEADD(DD,7,CAST(@today AS DATE))
    end
return
end
```

I getting this ERROR:

> Incorrect syntax near 'DATEADD'.

Comment: use
@date=DATEADD(DD,7,CAST(@today AS DATE))
need to assign to any variable.

Comment: Why `CAST` the variable to a `DATE`? It's already a `DATE`. And I thought T-SQL was meant to be a set-approach language? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoud use set befor DateADD. see belowe code:

```
   alter function GetNextDays()
returns @somedays table
(

dayDate date
)
as
begin
declare @today date=getdate()
declare @index int=0
while @index<3
    begin
    insert @somedays(dayDate) values(@today)
    set @index=@index+1;
    set @today= DATEADD(DD,7,cast(@today as date))
    end
return
end
```

chnage this Line:

```
DATEADD(DD,7,CAST(@today AS DATE))
```

with :

```
set @today= DATEADD(DD,7,cast(@today as date))
```

Comment: Getting rid of the loop entirely would be a better approach.

Comment: Although this is a working solution, I thinkg the one @SeanLange made is much better because it's set-based.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use a loop for this at all. You should be using a numbers or tally table. I put this in a cte here for you to see. I have a view on my system that I can use for this type of thing without the need for loops.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select DATEADD(day, N, cast(getdate() as DATE))
from cteTally
where N <= 3
```